# Retrieving User's Name from Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Employee evaluation form which stores the supervisor (FTO) and employee (FTE) in the database  by their ID number (EID).

I can retrieve the data and display the EID of both the supervisor and the employee, but how can I setup it up to pull their names from the user table and display those?

My User Table

```
ID | EID | first name | last name | email | password
```

Evaluation Table

```
ID | ftoEid | fteEid | date | rating1 | etc...
```

Currently using in the model:

```
$dor = Dor::find($id);
return view('dor.show', compact('dor'));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since you get the entry with ftoEid and fteEid back I'd say you need a join then but there is an easier way, if you can change your setup a little bit.
Look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships
Basically each entry in the evaluation table belongs to a user by ftoEid and a user by fteEid.
What I would set up here is a one to many. One entry in the evaluation table can belong to N users(In your case 2)

Comment: To keep it simple have a column in the users table called "role" which is then either supervisor or employee.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up relationships.

```
class Evaluation extends Model {
   public function user() {
      return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'fteEid');
   }
}

Dor::find(1)->user->first_name;
```

Your field names are confusing so I am not sure if they are correct; hopefully you get the idea.